# Free reports for c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, report

I'm writing desktop app in c# and I need some free reporting system.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I'm using SQLite as DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server Reporting, which can be downloaded as part of SQL Server Express 2008.

Comment: Yeah it was nice of him to down vote me, when he didn't specify he was using SQLite in the first place.  :)

Comment: Doesn't matter if he is using SQLite, he can still download and use SQL Server Reporting.

Comment: +1 for mson - we use SQL Server Reporting Services in our product that uses an Access database for data storage just fine.

Comment: My application runs on machines with very little RAM (256 MB).This is one of the reasons why I chose SQLite, and not SQL Express. I do not want to launch unnecessary services if I do not have to.

Comment: @šljaker - SSRS is different from SQL Express - neither requires the other to be installed. You just need the redistributable components (i.e. ReportViewer) on the developer machine, that is all. We populate our reports using generic collections of objects. Obviously these collections can be created based on whatever data source you want. Don't go thinking that SSRS can directly connect to random arbitrary databases... you do have *some* work to do here!!

Answer (score 1):

[Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) has been available to windows developers as a free reporting system since VB6 (if I'm not mistaken).  Free to redistribute and use.

Comment: Can it be used with visual studio express?

Comment: No it doesn't come with visual studio express.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I think you'll have to have Pro or above.

Comment: Aside from your answer truly is a valid response, I still want to DV you for bring up Crystal!

Comment: @Chris--while crystal is the bane of many a developer, its free and ready to use.

Comment: I've heard so many horror stories about crystal, I'm so glad I've never had to use it. I mean come on who would think embedding the connection string to the report server INSIDE the report was smart.

Comment: Is there an ODBC data source available for SQLite?

Comment: We tried using free Crystal for an in-house project, and it went poorly, primarily because we had strange paper sizes we wanted to print reports to.  Crystal Reports works okay, just as long as you don't try to do things with it that are marginally documented, I guess.

Comment: There are some odbc connectors for sqlite floating around...  "other" may have been an unfortunate choice of word.

Comment: Crystal Reports is an awful beast.  DO NOT USE IT.  It's one of those products that should have died a long time ago, but lingers because as P.T. Barnum says... there is a sucker born every minute - too bad they often are in deciding role...

Comment: In what way is Crystal Reports free?  The server license is well over 5k and they nickle and dime you to death as well.  Also, consultants that configure server and reports for Crystal are very expensive because the tool is arcane and the training is expensive.  We have to pay our CR writere $1500/day...

Comment: I do not want to buy PRO version of Visual Studio just for reports.
If someone will later maintain the code, why would he have to buy the licensed Visual Studio? Reporting service must work with the Express version

Comment: You don't want to buy PRO version then you'd better find a free report writing package that doesn't come with any plugins/templates for VS.  I'm sure they are out there.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. You assumed that I use SQL Server and VS PRO =)

Comment: I assumed the OEM came with Express, which it does not.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Not all the versions of Crystal Reports runtime are redistributable as free. The one that is 2005 redistributable is the free one but to create reports you need Visual Studio 2005 professional version or above.

But Crystal reports is a good choice for reporting in C# .Net.

Comment: OEM redistributable is included with VS Pro.  They do offer a pay version with more features, better designer etc.

Comment: We have created a layer of abstraction using C# over the database so we don't write queries in the report designer instead provide generic lists as datasource to the report which makes the database independant.

Answer (score 1):

They have a small overview of some open-source reporting tools at csharp-source.net:

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly you expect from a reporting engine but there is some reporting support embedded in SharpDevelop ([SharpDevelop Reports](http://sharpdevelopreports.net/MainPage.ashx)) that can also be used as stand alone.

It is licensed under LPGL, but doesn't provide any charting capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

The stand alone reporting version of the SQL server report services (SSRS) can be used. It does not require SQL server and comes with visual studio. It works pretty good. It is free and I believe it does not have to be licensed in order to release it with your app but research this before doing so.

Comment: OP wants it for Express.  But its a nice link, I'll remember that.

Comment: @Will this is irrelevant - works fine regardless of underlying database.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not free but since you brought up your working with Visual Studio Express, a cheaper option than upgrading to a full copy of Visual Studio is [Telerik Reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx).

I haven't used it yet but I've had alot of success with their controls in the past and just had my workplace purchase the license that includes all the control and the reporting and at some point I'll be using Telerik reporting personally.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the desire to stay inexpensive and would vote for SSRS in addition to your SQLite implmentation.  However, the Dundas product is fantastic...

I'm not sure who controls the purse strings, but you can make some flashy displays/reports/dashboards with Dundas.  We software developers often focus on the code - it's beauty, it's elegance, it's terseness.  We often forget that sales drive the existence/continuance of the product.  And sales is driven by - ooh, look at that shiney thing!